# jQuery: droppable doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Drag and drop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">        
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li> Milk </li>
        <li> Bread </li>
    </ul>
    <div id ="list"></div>
</body> </html>
```

Css file, works very good:
"It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details"

```
ul { padding: 0; list-style: none; color: red } #list {
width: 450px;
height: 450px;
background-color: #f0f0f0;
border: 1px solid #000;
overflow: auto; } #list.border {
border-width: 2px; }
```

jQuery file:

```
$(document).ready(function () { $( 'li' ).draggable({containment: 'document', revert: true, start: function()
{
    contents = $(this).text();
}

}); $('#list').droppable({hoverClass: 'border', drop: function()
{
    $('#list').append(contents + '<br />');
}

}); });
```

The function "droppable" doesn't work and I can't notice the bug.

Answer (score 0):

You really should try to keep your code readable, by keeping the indents and so on. If you did, you would have notices, that:

- You define the `droppable`-Objects outside your `$(document).ready()`-Function, what causes errors, and
- You close your `$(document).ready()`-Function two times (there is a `)};` to much at the end of your code.

```js
$(document).ready(function () { 
  $( 'li' ).draggable({
    containment: 'document', 
    revert: true, 
    start: function() {
      contents = $(this).text();
    }
    
  $('#list').droppable({
    hoverClass: 'border', 
    drop: function() {
      $('#list').append(contents + '<br />');
    }
  }); 
});
```

Try this code, it could work.